# "Real" orphan removal with Doctrine/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, relational-database

I have two entities linked together by a `ManyToMany` relationship in a Doctrine/MySQL project.

A `Client` entity:

```php
class Client
{
    [...]

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="ClientTag")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="clients_tags")

     */
    protected $tags;
}
```

And a `ClientTag` entity:

```php
class ClientTag
{
    [...]

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=45)
     */
    protected $label;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=7)
     */
    protected $color;
}
```

So I have the ability to associate multiple clients to one tag, and vice-versa, great.

But I can't find a way to automatically **remove a tag when there is no more clients referencing it**.

I tried to use `orphanRemoval` on the `ManyToMany` annotation but it doesn't do what I thought.. **Orphan** removal should imply exactly what I described above but it removes the tag when the reference to its parent is removed, not considering other entities like I need to.

If a client removes a tag but this tag is still used by 2 other clients, I don't consider it "*orphan*" as it still has one or more entities referencing it.

Of course I could solve the case by doing a query and removing it myself if I don't find any parent, but I wonder if Doctrine or MySQL have a built in way to do this (that will be far more optimized) ?

Any idea?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I wonder if this answers your question. [Bidirectional many-to-many cascade remove and orphanRemoval operations in doctrine](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/h0jt/bidirectional-many-to-many-cascade-remove-and-orphan-removal-operations-in-doctrine)

Comment: I'm afraid not. He's talking about the junction table which is not where my problem is. **Using the entities he's taking as example**, 
I'm searching a way to remove a `tournament` when there is no more `team` associated with it (of course without doing a select count manually..). That's what "orphan removal" sounds like to me, like : "remove this entity if is has no more relation with this other entity".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Officially `orphanRemoval` isn't supported for `ManyToMany` relations in doctrine.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-manytomany

The orphan removal in this case is ambiguous.
You can either just understand the relations (the jointable entries) to the deleted entity as the orphans or the related entity. 
From a database point of view it would be the jointable entries. 
From an ORM point of view it's the related entities.

Thing is both ways are correct depending on the use case. For example in an `Article` <-> `Category` relation you would want to remove the article from all associated categories on deletion, but you wouldn't want to throw away the whole category just because it's empty at this moment.

I'm guessing that's the reason why Doctrine doesn't officially mention the `orphanRemoval` option for `ManyToMany` because it's unclear and to fully support both variants the current implementation isn't enough.

Hope that was somehow understandable. 
In your case though you'll probably need to clean up unused tags yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but adding an "orphanRemoval" on the `$tags` attribute of the `Client` entity doesn't seem ambigous to me.
You are in a relation between `Client` and `ClientTag` and tell the system to remove any `ClientTag` not associated with a `Client` entity.
I may miss something but from what I understand right now, it seems doable. 
The junction table is not part of the equation, you only need to know if there is a "link" between the two entities through the relation, no matter if its by using a foreign key in one of the entities or a junction table.

Comment: You're not wrong. It is doable for sure, but doctrine just doesn't do it. The main point was that orphanRemoval isn't supported for ManyToMany (officially), and the unofficial support which you have described just cleans up orphans in the junction table. Everything else was just me gibbering about why it's not supported possibly. The real reason can probably only be answered by members of the doctrine team directly.

Comment: Ok thanks for your time. You answered my question, there is no built in way to handle what I need to do. 
That's sad because I wanted to avoid doing myself a select count to see if the entity is now an orphan, but I guess I have no choice.
I let the question opened for 1 ou 2 days, if nobody comes with another answer I'll accept yours.
Have a good day.